trying to change permissions for my E partition so I can edit files on it
My E partition (sda3 - VFAT) is seen and used by my Win7 partition (sda2 - NTFS) as a data storage partition, where I can write/copy and edit documents and save them there.
I want to use it the same way with my Ubuntu partition (sda5 - EXT4)...
But, when I use Ubuntu 24.04lts it can only read/write to it, but try to edit the documents, it will not let me save/overwrite the file. I get a 'Write Error. The file could not be written', yet it will let me copy files to/from the partition, just not 'alter' them.
I tried to chmod the document file I wish to edit, but I'll get this error 'chmod: changing permissions of 'xxxxxx.xxx': Read-only file system'. Same thing trying to change permissions for the directory it is in including its subfiles - same error. Even chmod the partition gives same error...
Apparently, anything on this partition is uneditable by linux, but win7 can do anything to it. HOW DO I CHANGE THIS?!?
...be gentle, for I am really a seasoned 'newbie' having had only a few LINUX ADMIN courses under my belt ;-)
Went into win7 and changed the E partition to share, with read and change permissions - didn't do squat!
From 'sudo parted -l':
Model: ATA TOSHIBA MQ01ABD0 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size    Type      File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  106MB  105MB   primary   ntfs         boot
 2      106MB   105GB  105GB   primary   ntfs
 3      105GB   157GB  52.4GB  primary   fat32
 4      157GB   500GB  343GB   extended
 5      157GB   262GB  105GB   logical   ext4
 6      262GB   388GB  126GB   logical   ext4
 7      388GB   500GB  112GB   logical   ext4

btw: I use Ubuntu 24.04lts for browsing now that suspend and hibernate work - win7 is there for 'backup' when linux f/u, non-secure browsing (no online banking, med portals, etc.), and windoz only programs :-\

don't know if thisinfo helps - a part of my fstab file:      #                 # /boot/efi was on /dev/sda3 during installation
#UUID=30E3-0E45  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1

Windows formats like FAT32, NTFS and exFAT do not support Linux ownership & permissions. Defaults are set when mounting & cannot then be changed. Are Windows partitions basic or did you change to dynamic? Post this: sudo parted -l Windows 7 is very obsolete and should not be used to connect to Internet. If you have UEFI install with ESP, the default mount is 0077 for security reasons, to prevent unauthorized access. Use another partition, preferable NTFS for data sharing across Windows & Linux.

I use a dual boot - my grub lets me select either to Ubuntu 24.04lts, or win7... E is just there - acessible to write to and from just can't alter/delete whats on it

SO, I'll need to move the data, reformat E partition (sda3) to NTFS, and THEN move data back and all will be possible?

You should always have backups of all your data. At least /home, list of installed apps and perhaps some settings in /etc. And in Windows backups of all your data.

forget 'backup' - I do image w/Ghost4Linux!!!

Thanks, oldfred - you hit it on the nose... no way anything you can try is going to get that fat32 partition to cooperate with anything linux!
Using Win7 I moved all the data to temp folder, REFORMATTED "E" drive (not 'quick format') to NTFS. Dumped the contents back.
Back to Ubuntu 24.04lts file manager gave an error accessing "E", so unmounted, then mounted it and now able to read, write, alter, delete, etc. the <new NTFS "E"> partition (...no more sda3 VFAT ~ now sda3 NTFS and a happy camper!) Able to edit documents, create links to, etc. that I was unable to do using fat32 :-|
